# How to use setSelectedDataAsync() in Excel 2016 for Windows

Tags: office365, office365api, office-js, office365-apps

I'm writing an Add in for Microsoft Excel and try to use the setSelectedDataAsync() function. It works fine in Excel 2013, Excel Online and Excel 2016 for Mac, but NOT in Excel 2016 in Windows.

I'm using the following function to test:

```
function testWriting() {
        var test = [["one"], ["two"]];
        Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(test, 
             { 
                 coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Matrix 
             }, 
             function(result) {
        });
    }
```

It works when I mark to empty cells, but not when I mark filled cells I want to overwrite. Is that a bug in Excel 2016 or how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

that's by design. the setSelectedDataAsync method fails if it overrides existing cells with values.

Comment: So how would you resolve this? What function would you use in Excel 2016 on Windows instead? The function would also need to be available in Excel 2013, which makes this so tricky.

Comment: fortunately for you there is a very rich set of Excel APIs available for you in 2016. you could verify the values overlap, move the cells if needed etc.